# Elasticsearch error when re-running jhipster project: Error creating bean with name 'userSearchRepository'

Tags: elasticsearch, jhipster

**After generating jhipster with elasticsearch I imported jdl file below.**

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "com.nokat.gazna",
      "nativeLanguage": "en"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "6.4.1",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "baseName": "gazna",
    "packageName": "com.nokat.gazna",
    "packageFolder": "com/nokat/gazna",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "cacheProvider": "ehcache",
    "enableHibernateCache": true,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "jwtSecretKey": "NWNmMWNiOWM1YTQ2YjczYTkwYTlkODBmNDk5MzczOTA5MGIxNTk1ZGMzNzRjMDNhZTRmMWVkOGZiMWUzMDk5NTQzOGZhYTBlYWY0ZjQ4M2M5YzhjMDYwMmI1NTA1NjQ4M2EzYzE4NDgzZGVmMGE0ZTVlNDY3ZDQzOTU5NDdmMTU=",
    "embeddableLaunchScript": false,
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "entitySuffix": "",
    "dtoSuffix": "DTO",
    "otherModules": [],
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "clientPackageManager": "npm",
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "languages": [
      "en",
      "ru",
      "tr"
    ],
    "blueprints": [],
    "skipClient": true
  }
}
```

```
entity Region {
    regionName String
}

entity Country {
    countryName String
}

// an ignored comment
/** not an ignored comment */
entity Location {
    streetAddress String,
    postalCode String,
    city String,
    stateProvince String
}

entity Department {
    departmentName String required
}

/**
 * Task entity.
 * @author The JHipster team.
 */
entity Task {
    title String,
    description String
}

/**
 * The Employee entity.
 */
entity Employee {
    /**
    * The firstname attribute.
    */
    firstName String,
    lastName String,
    email String,
    phoneNumber String,
    hireDate Instant,
    salary Long,
    commissionPct Long
}

entity Job {
    jobTitle String,
    minSalary Long,
    maxSalary Long
}

entity JobHistory {
    startDate Instant,
    endDate Instant,
    language Language
}

enum Language {
    FRENCH, ENGLISH, SPANISH
}

relationship OneToOne {
    Country{region} to Region
}

relationship OneToOne {
    Location{country} to Country
}

relationship OneToOne {
    Department{location} to Location
}

relationship ManyToMany {
    Job{task(title)} to Task{job}
}

// defining multiple OneToMany relationships with comments
relationship OneToMany {
    Employee{job} to Job,
    /**
    * A relationship
    */
    Department{employee} to
    /**
    * Another side of the same relationship
    */
    Employee
}

relationship ManyToOne {
    Employee{manager} to Employee
}

// defining multiple oneToOne relationships
relationship OneToOne {
    JobHistory{job} to Job,
    JobHistory{department} to Department,
    JobHistory{employee} to Employee
}

// Set pagination options
paginate JobHistory, Employee with infinite-scroll
paginate Job with pagination

// Use Data Transfert Objects (DTO)
// dto * with mapstruct

// Set service options to all except few
service all with serviceImpl except Employee, Job

// Set an angular suffix
// angularSuffix * with mySuffix
```

**First time it runs without error. But when I re-run the project I get an error.**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [D:\Projects\JHipster\Gazna\backend\target\classes\com\nokat\gazna\service\UserService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userSearchRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.NumberKeyedRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.exception.JestElasticsearchException: Cannot execute jest action , response code : 400 , error : {"root_cause":[{"type":"resource_already_exists_exception","reason":"index [user/ZZ-RPvKlRHWJnrd50KVGQA] already exists","index_uuid":"ZZ-RPvKlRHWJnrd50KVGQA","index":"user"}],"type":"resource_already_exists_exception","reason":"index [user/ZZ-RPvKlRHWJnrd50KVGQA] already exists","index_uuid":"ZZ-RPvKlRHWJnrd50KVGQA","index":"user"} , message : null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:847)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at com.nokat.gazna.GaznaApp.main(GaznaApp.java:63)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userSearchRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.NumberKeyedRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.exception.JestElasticsearchException: Cannot execute jest action , response code : 400 , error : {"root_cause":[{"type":"resource_already_exists_exception","reason":"index [user/ZZ-RPvKlRHWJnrd50KVGQA] already exists","index_uuid":"ZZ-RPvKlRHWJnrd50KVGQA","index":"user"}],"type":"resource_already_exists_exception","reason":"index [user/ZZ-RPvKlRHWJnrd50KVGQA] already exists","index_uuid":"ZZ-RPvKlRHWJnrd50KVGQA","index":"user"} , message : null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1255)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.NumberKeyedRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.exception.JestElasticsearchException: Cannot execute jest action , response code : 400 , error : {"root_cause":[{"type":"resource_already_exists_exception","reason":"index [user/ZZ-RPvKlRHWJnrd50KVGQA] already exists","index_uuid":"ZZ-RPvKlRHWJnrd50KVGQA","index":"user"}],"type":"resource_already_exists_exception","reason":"index [user/ZZ-RPvKlRHWJnrd50KVGQA] already exists","index_uuid":"ZZ-RPvKlRHWJnrd50KVGQA","index":"user"} , message : null
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.lambda$getTargetRepositoryViaReflection$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:513)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:513)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:305)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:67)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.exception.JestElasticsearchException: Cannot execute jest action , response code : 400 , error : {"root_cause":[{"type":"resource_already_exists_exception","reason":"index [user/ZZ-RPvKlRHWJnrd50KVGQA] already exists","index_uuid":"ZZ-RPvKlRHWJnrd50KVGQA","index":"user"}],"type":"resource_already_exists_exception","reason":"index [user/ZZ-RPvKlRHWJnrd50KVGQA] already exists","index_uuid":"ZZ-RPvKlRHWJnrd50KVGQA","index":"user"} , message : null
    at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.mapper.DefaultErrorMapper.mapError(DefaultErrorMapper.java:30)
    at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.execute(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:1126)
    at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.executeWithAcknowledge(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:1136)
    at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.createIndex(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:197)
    at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.createIndexWithSettings(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:1345)
    at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.createIndexIfNotCreated(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:1330)
    at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.createIndex(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:178)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.createIndex(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:96)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.<init>(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:87)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.NumberKeyedRepository.<init>(NumberKeyedRepository.java:36)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:172)
    ... 46 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

**When I delete nodes in target/elasticsearch/data/nodes folder it runs succesfully but when I try to re-run again it fails with same error.**

I am new to jhipster and I didn't do any code changes. Could you please help to solve this issue?

Comment: A user has already reported few months ago but could not reproduce, I think you add a comment to it with your own required details (run `jhipster info`). See https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/10199

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this two commands in your terminal

```
./mvnw clean
./mvnw
```