# JHipster, How to set up production with elasticsearch? (Windows 10)

Tags: elasticsearch, jhipster

I have created a new project and am trying to set up the production environment properly. I haven't added any entities yet so it's still an empty JHipster project! Unfortunately Elasticsearch keeps throwing an exception and it doesn't work out of the box.

Exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [C:\Users\kleinoth\IdeaProjects\Faktura-ALL\faktura\target\classes\de\bouss\faktura\service\UserService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userSearchRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to execute action
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
        at de.bouss.faktura.FakturaApp.main(FakturaApp.java:63)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userSearchRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to execute action
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
        ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to execute action
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:217)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.lambda$getTargetRepositoryViaReflection$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:521)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:521)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:506)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:72)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:312)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297)
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:212)
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:67)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
        ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to execute action
        at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.execute(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:1214)
        at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.executeWithAcknowledge(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:1219)
        at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.indexExists(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:940)
        at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.createIndexIfNotCreated(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:1429)
        at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.createIndex(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:172)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.createIndex(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:99)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.<init>(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:89)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.<init>(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:39)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:204)
        ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.searchbox.client.config.exception.CouldNotConnectException: Could not connect to http://localhost:9200
        at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.execute(JestHttpClient.java:73)
        at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.execute(JestHttpClient.java:63)
        at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.execute(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:1207)
        ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9200 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
        at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.executeRequest(JestHttpClient.java:136)
        at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.execute(JestHttpClient.java:70)
        ... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:107)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
        at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
        ... 66 common frames omitted
```

There is already a similar question. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58553331/elasticsearch-error-when-re-running-jhipster-project-error-creating-bean-with-n).

Suggested solution:

```
./mvnw clean
./mvnw
```

So here is the workflow i tried

1. `docker-compose -f src\main\docker\mysql.yml up -d && docker-compose -f src\main\docker\elasticsearch.yml up -d`
2. `mvnw clean && mvnw -Pprod`

But unfortunately this does not work. Still the same error.

I also downgraded elasticseach to version 6.4.3 but that didn't make any difference either.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Infos:

````
INFO! Using JHipster version installed locally in current project's node_modules
INFO! Executing jhipster:info
Welcome to the JHipster Information Sub-Generator

##### **JHipster Version(s)**

```
faktura@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT C:\Users\kleinoth\IdeaProjects\Faktura-ALL\faktura
`-- generator-jhipster@6.10.5

```


##### **JHipster configuration, a `.yo-rc.json` file generated in the root folder**


<details>
<summary>.yo-rc.json file</summary>
<pre>
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "de.bouss.faktura"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "6.10.5",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "baseName": "faktura",
    "packageName": "de.bouss.faktura",
    "packageFolder": "de/bouss/faktura",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "cacheProvider": "hazelcast",
    "enableHibernateCache": true,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "jwtSecretKey": "YourJWTSecretKeyWasReplacedByThisMeaninglessTextByTheJHipsterInfoCommandForObviousSecurityReasons",
    "embeddableLaunchScript": false,
    "useSass": true,
    "clientPackageManager": "npm",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "clientTheme": "flatly",
    "clientThemeVariant": "primary",
    "creationTimestamp": 1610033962999,
    "testFrameworks": ["gatling", "cucumber", "protractor"],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "entitySuffix": "",
    "dtoSuffix": "DTO",
    "otherModules": [],
    "enableTranslation": false,
    "blueprints": []
  }
}

</pre>
</details>


##### **JDL for the Entity configuration(s) `entityName.json` files generated in the `.jhipster` directory**

<details>
<summary>JDL entity definitions</summary>

<pre>

</pre>
</details>


##### **Environment and Tools**

openjdk version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.9.1+1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.9.1+1, mixed mode)

git version 2.29.2.windows.2

node: v14.15.3

npm: 6.14.10

yeoman: 3.1.1

Docker version 20.10.0, build 7287ab3

docker-compose version 1.27.4, build 40524192

INFO! Congratulations, JHipster execution is complete!
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error after all.
It was really strange because sometimes everything started normally. After a closer look, the Elasticsearch Docker container did not always start. Error code 137! This of course made it impossible for my app to connect to ES.
I have increased the resources of Docker (described [here](https://www.petefreitag.com/item/848.cfm)). Now everything is running fine!